# Package/function to convert the word to one hot vector in Python NLP

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

Is there a package or function in NLP which can be used to convert the word into an one hot vector.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to convert words to one hot encoded vectors. Since I do not know the data structure you store your data. I assume it is going to be a list

> from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer 
>   samples = ['The', 'dog','mouse','elephant']
>   tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=len(samples))

This builds the word index

> tokenizer.fit_on_texts(samples)

one hot representation

> one_hot_results = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(samples, mode='binary')

By changing the mode from binary to 'tfidf' or 'count', you can make a matrix of any type, apart from one hot.

You can achieve the same result using other packages like sklearn. But it does involve a bit more lines of code.